# How to connect mark's of list with line?

Tags: css, html-lists

I have to connect marc's(blue) between each list. I want to connect them with a blue line. But I can not find a way to do it. It is especially complicated because the distance between

can change. So, I can not make a line with fix height. I have to make space between bullets flexible.

```css
.my-cv{
    list-style-type: disc;
}
.my-cv  li{
    color: #5dc5ef;
}
.my-cv  span{
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="my-cv" dir="rtl">
                            <li>
                                <span>
                                    1995-2001 בנגב בוגר הפקולטה לרפואה באוניברסיטת בן גוריון
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span>
                                    2002-2003 סטאז' בביה"ח כרמל בחיפה
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span>
                                    2007-2010, 2003-2006 התמחות בכירורגיה כללית בביה"ח "שיבא" בתל השומר

                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span>
                                    2010-2012 תת-התמחות בניתוחי קיצור קיבה בביה"ח "קליבלנד קליניק" בקליבלנד, אוהיו

                                </span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
```

Comment: I have to make space between bullets flexible  - it is a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took me a while.. but I managed to (hard code) a line between the dots.

`li:before` draws a line between all dots with the height of 30px.

I'd suggest using [Less](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) to make this more dynamic.

```css
    .my-cv {
      list-style-type: desc;
      
    }

    .my-cv li {
      color: #5dc5ef;
    }

    .my-cv span {
      color: black;
    }

    li:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      right: 33px;
      border-left: 1px solid #5dc5ef;
      width: 1px;
      height: 30px; // change with my-cv.height in less
    }

    li:first-child:before {
      top: 23px;//Don't draw before first bullet
    }

    li:last-child:before {
      height: 6px; //Don't draw after last bullet
    }
```

```html
    <ul class="my-cv" dir="rtl">
      <li class="first-child">
        <span>
                                                    1995-2001 בנגב בוגר הפקולטה לרפואה באוניברסיטת בן גוריון
                                                </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>
                                                    2002-2003 סטאז' בביה"ח כרמל בחיפה
                                                </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>
                                                    2007-2010, 2003-2006 התמחות בכירורגיה כללית בביה"ח "שיבא" בתל השומר

                                                </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>
                                                    2010-2012 תת-התמחות בניתוחי קיצור קיבה בביה"ח "קליבלנד קליניק" בקליבלנד, אוהיו

                                                </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Yes, it works. I use SASS. Yes, I understood how to make it dynamic! Thank you for helping.